# How do I see the usage (API_CALL) of IBM Watson Assistant?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to see it automatically (through an api), however I do not know where to pick up how many calls the watson-assistant did.

How could you get this information?

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact API, at least not in Watson Assistant. There may be in the billing page.

The logs are your go-to place to get this information in one go though.

There are two versions of the API that work a little differently.

### V1

The billing is based on every call to Watson Assistant through the messaging app. So if you download the logs and count the number of responses, this is the number of calls.

There is exceptions to this. For example, if someone executed the GDPR delete command, then you would not have the count for the removed lines. Overall though it should give you a fairly accurate count.

### V2

The V2 uses a session based system. So when you make your connection the unique conversation ID becomes the count.

---

It's important to note that logs are only kept for 30 days (7 days for free version). So you need to factor that in when making the count.

You can pull logs through the API. There is some sample code here:

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/community/blob/master/watson-assistant/export_logs.py

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I've been researching even more and found this DOC that limits only cURL, this view:

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/metering-reporting

Response Json has an "API_CALL", but I wonder if anyone could use this api without using cURL